# Python: how to add a list to an existing txt file and it has to include the commas in the text file?

Tags: python

What I want to do:
I have a list now and want to add it to the bottom of the existing text file. However, when the new line is added, the commas doesn't appear

What I have done so far:
Current txt file:

```
food,bought
oranges,yes
strawberry,no
```

my code

```
choice=input("What fruit?")
item=[]
item.append(choice)
item.append("No")

with open('groceries.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.writelines(item)
```

result of my code

```
food,bought
oranges,yes
strawberry,no
applesno
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
food,bought
oranges,yes
strawberry,no
apples,no
```

I tried to add the comma eg. item.append(choice+",") but it will change the result when i use index later on
Any way to solve this?

Comment: `','.join(item)`

Comment: `file.writelines(",".join(item))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to join a list using `,`?

```
','.join(item)
```

This will give you:

```
apples,no
```

You can use it simply as:

```
file.writelines(",".join(item))
```